# Problem with docker - can't find package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem that I don't understand fully. I have a folder with docker-compose and Dockerfile. Container is being built, but I have error that npm can't find file or directory with package.json. When I'm mobing these 2 files to main root it's working like a charm. So probably there is a mistake in docker-compose or Dockerfile. Could someone advise me something, please.

app structure:

```
app
--docker-compose
----docker-compose.yml
----Dockerfile
--package.json
--...
```

```yaml
services:
  dev:
    container_name: animals_api_dev
    image: animals-api-dev:1.0.0
    build:
      context: ../
      target: development
      dockerfile: ./docker-compose/Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:debug
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=${MONGO_HOST}
      - MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT}
      - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - animals-api-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo-database
      - mongo-express
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  animals-api-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM node:18-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `volumes:` block is hiding everything in your application, but with contents from a different directory.  Delete it.

Looking at your file structure, with the `docker-compose.yml` file in a subdirectory, your `build: { context: }` correctly points back at the parent directory, and so the `COPY package*.json ./` gets the file out of that context directly correctly.  My expectation is that you can `docker-compose build` the image successfully.

When you run it, though, your `volumes:` mount hides *everything* in the image's `/usr/src/app` directory with the mounted directory.  In this case the directory you're mounting is `.`, the subdirectory containing the Compose file and nothing else, and your application is hidden.

You don't need this volume mount, and it can cause various sorts of problems and inconsistencies.  (It also hides the `node_modules` directory; the standard workaround for that causes changes in `package.json` to be ignored; and if your Dockerfile does anything at all other than install dependencies and copy files you won't see those results.)  Just delete it entirely.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev:
    build:  # consider moving Docker-related files to parent directory
      context: ../
      target: development
      dockerfile: ./docker-compose/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=${MONGO_HOST}
      - MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT}
      - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - mongo-database
      - mongo-express
      - redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    # without volumes:
    # without container_name: or image:
    # without command: (make sure Dockerfile has a `CMD`)
    # without networks: (delete all of them in the entire file)
```

Comment: how will this work if you need hmr/live-reloading to work? that's why the volumes part existed. i don't think this is the solution if you want hmr/live-reloading to work. i face the same error. everything works when i remove volumes but i need it for hmr to work. it works for others though -> https://jameschambers.co.uk/nextjs-hot-reload-docker-development

Comment: For day-to-day development, you can run `npm run start:debug` locally, without doing anything Docker-related, and work on your application that way.  When you go to deploy the application or if you need larger-scale integration testing, you can then build an immutable image out of it.